# Horizontal cropping animation for image on scroll

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, scroll, framer-motion

I tried to replicate this [effect](https://www.riveal.fr/agence/) but it snaps when you scroll up fast.

[codesandox](https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-usescroll-forked-rd82m2?file=/src/components/LoremIpsum.js). How to make it pleasing on the eyes?

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1427878)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well figured it out. Had to limit the width the img element was getting. console.log() showed width was reaching infinity because of scrolling which thereby put a delay on the return animation.

```
const maxWidth = 700. // actual maximum width of the image. 

img.style.width = `${width <= maxWidth ? width : maxWidth}px`;
```